# WCF send xml to Web Service and receive message

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, web, service

Please tell me, can i accomplished something like..
Some company has created CRM, this CRM provides some Web Services. I can communicate with this services via XML. So my question is can i create Windows Services with WCF which will be send some request ( every hour ) to Web Service and receive data from this web services.

Example:

1. At 9am, 10 am... WCF has sent request ( XML ) to Web Service:Hey CRM how many users you have?
2. Web Service received a message and response via XML: I got 10 users.
3. WCF received message: I got 10 users... and did something with it.

Please for some help. Articles, code sample, or key words what should i look for.

Comment: Can you add a service reference to the webservice that the CRM exposes ? (right click on references on your application and click add service reference, then add the URL to the webservice)

Comment: Thank everyone for your reply. I was not sure how to accomplish something like that, but i am pretty sure your answers will solve my problem. Thanks again, I gonna try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing in your question indicates the need for WCF, it sounds like all you need to do is create a SOAP reference (web reference) to this CRM Web Service and call it every hour.  This could be a console app or any app for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

If the provided web services are standard, WCF should be able to communicate with them.
Add a service reference, specify the URL, and if discovery (WSDL) is available, Visual Studio will allow you to quickly generate a proxy class that makes using the server very easy.

Scheduling the requests every hour is not related to wcf, use task scheduler or a manual solution for that.